# Как настроить высоту объекта внутри блока

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть блок, высота которого устанавливается в зависимости от контента внутри него (height: max-content). В основном высоту регулирует текст. И у меня с этим блоком две проблемы.

Между картинкой и блоком есть линия, которая занимает 100% высоты блока. Но когда высота задаётся автоматически, то эту линию не видно. Она срабатывает только при фиксированной высоте. С картинкой проблема такая-же, если задать ей 100% высоты, то её не будет видно в блоке без фиксированной высоты.
Как сделать, чтобы эти элементы было видно при высоте в 100% и автоматически устанавливаемой высоте?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавь пример разметки

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - я сделал это через padding-bottom: 50%, а высоту не задавал.
Такое решение сработало, но я не уверен что оно правильное, возможно есть варианты лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно прописать min-height для блока. Тогда если контента внутри блока будет больше, чем минимальная высота блока, то блок просто растянется.

Ну и второй вариант, задать padding.